# What can halt an attachment save with paperclip while using a s3 storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a activerecord model called "game" with an paperclip attachment called "image". I have included and extended an extension in this model which have a before_save and some after_save callbacks which all return true.

The problem is, when I do a create or update on a game, the attachment get not saved on my s3 bucket, BUT the table columns are saved correctly.

So I always get the "NoSuchKey" exception on the attachment url.

I figured out that there must be a problem with my extension but the really strange thing is, that I can't reproduce this bug in any case on my local machine nor on another server also with s3.

I read dozens of lines of code from paperclip, aws-s3, rails and my own application but I couldn't find a mistake.

I also tested the bug with a current database dump locally but it still works there.

**My question** is now, what can cancel a attachment save transaction?

Comment: just to be sure: is your bucket in the US?

Comment: my bucket is on s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: I bet :) but when you create it, you're asked the location of it. The aws gem only works with us based buckets

Comment: You might have to include some code. Hard to tell what might be going wrong in your model or before/after hooks without code samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was this line in a seperate action in the controller which was called sometimes:

```
Game.after_save.clear
```

After I've removed it, the feature worked properly.